# Is it possible to send sms via coding without manually typing?

Tags: android, sms

Hai i want to send the message via coding is it possible?

```
mobile number="xxx"
message="hai"
```

Anyboby kindly explain with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
String number = "6508570720";
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Test SMS Message", null, null);
```

Hope that helps!

REF: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/

Answer (score 1):

```
    //---sends an SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

More Information: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android